# Delete element from array and encode to JSON not working

Tags: php, json

I'd like to delete a specific element based on an ID from a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"test",
    "no":"312312"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"test2",
    "no":"4234234234"
  }
]
```

This is my PHP function:

```
function deleteNumber($id){
    $pb = file_get_contents("PhonebookDB.json");
    $tempArr = json_decode($pb);

    $key = array_search($id,  array_column($tempArr, 'id'));
    unset($tempArr[$key]);

    $updatedPB = json_encode($tempArr);
    file_put_contents("PhonebookDB.json", $updatedPB);

    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
```

This works if I delete the very last element. However it doesn't work if I try to delete any other element. I think the problem is that the JSON structure gets destroyed if I don't delete the last element. It looks like this if I delete the first element for example:

```
{
  "1":
    {
      "id":2,
      "name":"test2",
      "no":"4234234234"
    }
}
```

What is the problem here? Why does it work with the last element but not with others?

Comment: `array_column` is returning an empty array for me with your code, therefore `$key` is false, and it will delete the 0 element.

Comment: Your code works fine. You just need to call `$updatedPB = array_values( json_encode($tempArr) );` before you save the json.

Comment: @Sherif that worked (almost) for me, thanks! I had to use array_values like this however: json_encode(array_values($tempArr));

Comment: @ramy Yes, you're absolutely right there. I got it backwards. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is more readable for your case.

You could try something like this (not tested):

```
function deleteNumber($id){
   $pb = file_get_contents("PhonebookDB.json");

   $tempArr = array_filter(
       json_decode($pb, true), // 'true' guaranties that everything will be in an associative array
       function ($item) use ($id) {
            return $item['id'] !== $id;
       }
   );
   $tempArr = array_values($tempArr); // need to save an array structure in json

   $updatedPB = json_encode($tempArr);
   file_put_contents("PhonebookDB.json", $updatedPB);

   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
```